# How can I find out which use statement I need to add in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, namespaces

I created a Controller and named the class `DataTableController`. But now I get an error message

> InvalidArgumentException
>
> Cannot determine controller argument for
>   "App\Controller\DataTableController::usersAction()": the $request
>   argument is type-hinted with the non-existent class or interface:
>   "App\Controller\Request". Did you forget to add a use statement?

How do I find out what kind of use statement I need to add?

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use DataTables\DataTablesInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
*
* @Route("/users", name="users")
*
* @param Request $request
* @param DataTablesInterface $datatables
* @return JsonResponse
*/

class DataTableController extends Controller
{

  const ID = 'users';

  public function usersAction(Request $request, DataTablesInterface $datatables): JsonResponse
  {
    try {
      // Tell the DataTables service to process the request,
      // specifying ID of the required handler.
      $results = $datatables->handle($request, 'users');

      return $this->json($results);
    }
    catch (HttpException $e) {
      // In fact the line below returns 400 HTTP status code.
      // The message contains the error description.
      return $this->json($e->getMessage(), $e->getStatusCode());
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `use` is missing:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

---

`JsonResponse`, `HttpException` mays be missing too. Use your IDE autocomplete to import these classes

Comment: Yes, that is working now. Can you explain to me how to find those "use" with autocomplete? I use Atom

Comment: I personnaly use phpStorm.Atom looks like a text editor rather than an IDE. You could try some plugin for php autocoplete or symfony autocomplete ;)

Comment: Yes, I have php autocomplete and also Symfony autocomplete. But how do you do it exactly. You just write "use" and the editor recomends the rest?

Comment: Sorry, i do not use Atom.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to find it by running:

`php ./bin/console debug:autowiring`

In addition, you can run the same command but with a `--show-private` flag:

`php ./bin/console debug:container --show-private`

I hope this helps.